# Visual Studio Code compileOnSave Stopped Working

Tags: angular, compilation, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code 1.3 for Angular 7. compileOnSave was working perfectly up until yesterday, when it stopped without notice.

My tsconfig.json had compileOnSave set to false (not sure if it was true beforehand). I changed it to true and still didn't help.  Also, I hit cntrl-shift-B to open tasks and selected 'tsc: watch -tsconfig.json. This started a process that did some level of recompile after files changed and auto-saved, but didn't do a full recompile and refresh the browser.

This is happening in VS Code running under Linux, but not Windows. Same version of VS Code and same code base.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Upon installing VSCode on both Windows and Linux, `compileOnSave` was working. Not sure what caused it to stop working on Linux. I tried changing `compileOnSave` to true, but that didn't make a difference.